# Disabling automatic time update in Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3, ntp

I want to disable the automatic time update mechanism of raspberry pi 3 and then set a specific time for it. 
To do so, I disable ntp on the raspbian using the following code:

sudo timedatectl set-ntp 0

And after this, the ntp was disabled. But when I set the specific time again, after some minutes, the time gets updated automatically again. 
How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using raspian on your rpi3 you can normally disable ntp by executing:

```
sudo systemctl stop ntp.service
sudo systemctl disable ntp.service
```

and if you have a hardware real-time clock on the i2c bus also execute:

```
sudo systemctl stop fake-hwclock.service
sudo systemctl disable fake-hwclock.service
```